# OpenCV 3 Visual Studio 2017 debugging with call stack no .pdb files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, pdb-files

I installed OpenCV 3 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on my Surface Pro (Windows 10 64-bit). I am coding in C++.

I need to see where my program is tripping up at when it reaches a bug, however, if the bug is in the OpenCV source code I can not see it, so I am left with guessing what the problem is.

When I try to look in the call stack for an error, it can not load the pages where the source code is, instead it says the .pdb files are not loaded. The .pdb files do not exist on my system, I have searched for them. I have found solutions for if you have the .pdb files but have not been able to find anywhere that explains how to generate the .pdb files.

So here I am on this forum, can anyone help me out? It is extremely difficult to debug something when you do not know the problem.

Comment: ***if you have the .pdb files but have not been able to find anywhere that explains how to generate the .pdb files.*** If you compile opencv from source using CMake to generate project files for your version of Visual Studio it will have the pdb files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reinstall using CMake, now the .pdb files are there and being read fine! I can finally debug this properly woot-woot. Thanks, @drescherjm.